# Char counter not updating when opening modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page with an option to insert names.
Basically you click in the add button, a modal with an input and a char counter opens and you type what you want, click in the add button bellow the input and that name is added to the page. You can creat as many as you want.

The problem is: the char counter in the modal only updates when the input is focused. If your first name has let's say 5 letters, when you try to add a second name, the modal opens empty, but the char counter shows 75chars left instead of 80 until you click in the input, then goes back to  80 like it should. 
Also, when you try to edit an existing name, the char counter shows 80 left even tho there's a name already in the input. Then again, when you click in the input, the counter updates to the correct value.

This is a sample from the code, even tho you can't see a preview, it has the code related to the problem:

https://embed.plnkr.co/rDbeal3nFmeitXQEkP55/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to listen for keyup and change events nor for the function updateCount, all you need to do is use ng-model, like this:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': revenue.name.$invalid }">
     <label>{{ 'revenues.form.name.label'|trans }}</label>
     <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.name" ng-required="true" maxlength="80" placeholder="{{ 'revenues.form.name.placeholder'|trans }}">
</div>

<span>You have {{80 - model.name.length}} characters left.</span>
```

Here is a [working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0yFYx1WBSLa6GeIS1N1n?p=preview).

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want the span to change color based on the char count, just use ng-class:

```
<span ng-class="{'red-text': model.name.length >= 70, 'green-text': model.name.length == 10}">You have {{80 - model.name.length}} characters left.</span>
```

red-text and green-text are sample css classes:

```
.red-text{
    color:red;
}
.green-text{
    color:green;
}
```

Here's the [updated plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/7OD2hv4NJvaTwIbztipN?p=preview)

Comment: That span gives me an error saying "Variable "model" does not exist in (...)"

Comment: It has to match what you put inside "ng-model" in the input, are you sure it's model.name?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. I just added the span, right bellow the the div with the input and it gives that error.

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with the scope. Can you show the updated code?

Comment: Silly me, I was adding it to the wrong place. It doesn't give that error now, but it doesn't work either: shows always '80' even when typing.
I just replaced the var span in the countdown.js with the one you gave

Comment: I wouldn't use countdown.js at all if I were you. I see you're generating a span inside of it, and this breaks MVC standards: the DOM should not be changed in there. Instead, add the span to the HTML just like I did in my example, and you can get rid of countdown.js completely

Comment: I might not need it for generating the span itself, but I need it to change the color of the counter ( inside the var updateCount). Can't I just add the span to the html and delete the code that is generating it, leaving just the other stuff there?

Comment: You can, but it's extremely bad practice and it's likely the source of the errors. To make it change color, you can use ng-class, I updated the plnkr to change the text color based on the char count

Comment: Updated my answer too.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I'm giving you the right answer because it's what I'm looking for and I know it works, even if I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Thank you, hope it works :) if it still doesn't, you can update your question with the new code and I'll look into it